# Como eu pego um valor em Lua sem usar o io.read()?

Tags: lua

Digamos que eu tenha algo tipo

```
a = io.read()
a = tonumber(a)
if a then
    print(a,a^2-1)
end
```

Tem outra maneira de pegar essa entrada sem ser o `io.read()`?

Comment: Porque precisa outra maneira?

Comment: so fiquei curioso se existe outra maneira alem do io.read()

Comment: Pega valor de onde? Arquivo, digitação do usuário, ou o que?

Comment: digitação de usuario de preferencia, mas pode ser de arquivo tbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pronto na biblioteca é isso aí mesmo. Sempre tem várias formas de obter o mesmo, mas se quer ler do console é a melhor forma. Exemplo:

```
local stdin = io.stdin:lines()
for line in stdin do
    print(line)
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Fc3FLd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/buxhqnms-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ReadLines.lua).

Se quiser ler outras fontes tem vários outras formas. Tem na [documentação](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.7).

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda :D